# Signals and Slots with Qtoolbutton

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have created a ToolButton with my qt designer and Im trying to connect it to a slot.
I wrote this

```
connect(ui->toolButton_addfiles, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(changeDirectory()));
```

Im able to run the program but when I press the button I see the following log into my qt Application Output :

```
   Object::connect: No such signal QToolButton::triggered() in ../RightDoneIt/rightdoneit.cpp:10
    Object::connect:  (sender name:   'toolButton_addfiles')
    Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'RightDoneIt')
```

- If I change the toolButton_addfile to some action like (actionChange_addfile) it will work fine.

How can I make this connection work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, there's no signal `triggered()` but `triggered(QAction*)` in the [`QToolButton`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qtoolbutton.html).

**Edit**
In the connect function you must have the signal signature like `triggered(QAction*)` since `QToolButton` class has no signal `triggered()` (with no parameter) declared

Comment: No, the slot doesn't need to take an QAction*. It can also take no arguments at all. If a slot has less arguments than the signal, the trailing arguments are just discarded.

Comment: triggered(QAction*) didnt work as well. I fixed that with the clicked() signal. Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: @user387221: that gave the same signal not found error? weird. Or did just nothing happen on click?

Comment: nothing happened. no application output, no error and the slot was never executed.

Comment: `triggered(QAction*)` only fires when you add some QAction via `addAction(...)` and select that action in the dropdown of the toolbutton.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the auto-connection process of Qt.

In the class referencing your UI, create a slot called :

on_toolButton_addfiles_clicked();

Exemple :

See : [A Dialog With Auto-Connect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/designer-using-a-component.html)

```
class ImageDialog : public QDialog, private Ui::ImageDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ImageDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void on_okButton_clicked();
};
```

Hope this helps !

Edit : No **triggered** signals in qAbstractButton. See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractbutton.html

Answer (score 1):

QToolButton() has the signal method **triggered(QAction *)**, this signal is to be addressed if triggering of the related QAction connected to the QToolbutton  is of interest. At the same time  QToolButton is inherited from QAbstractButton(), which has the **toggled(bool checked)** signal. If you want to catch the signal triggered by pressing/unpressing the tool button, you may do as following:

```
   auto toolbutton = new QToolButton(this);
     connect(toolbutton , &QAbstractButton::toggled, this, []() { // your code });
```

Alternatively (I have not checked if this solution works), you may define explicitly, what signal to be caught

```
    connect(toolbutton , qOverload<bool>(&QToolButton::toggled), this, [](bool val) { // your code});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're creating a QAction, adding it to the QToolButton and trying to connect it to a slot in your own class?

You can connect your slot to either the QToolButton::triggered(QAction*) signal or directly to the QAction::triggered() signal. Either way, the QAction must be added to the QToolButton through QWidget::addAction(QAction*), the slot's method signature must match the signal's signature, and the connect invocation must include the signal/slot parameters, not just the names of the signal and slot.